# Practical Application of Kadane algorithm

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, optimization

[Kadane Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) is used to solve the maximum subarray problem which in simpler terms is to find the highest possible value of a continuous sub array in an array.

One often cited application of Kadane Algorithm is that given the prices of the stock over X days , on which days should we buy and sell the stock in order to maximize given profit. These example is not practical at all as it is impossible to predict future prices of stocks and hence impossible to apply it .

What are some real world application of Kadane algorithm?

Comment: Your textbook is being facetious.